# Detect if MediaBrowserServiceCompat is running

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm using this [example code](https://github.com/tutsplus/background-audio-in-android-with-mediasessioncompat/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/tutsplus/backgroundaudio) to build a `MediaPlayer Service`.  I have it more or less working, however if a user returns to the `Activity` that contains the media controls, I need to detect what state the `MediaPlayer` is in.  The code I'm currently using throws a `NullReferenceException` error in `onResume` because `getPlaybackState()` is always `null`.

I'm new to using `MediaSessionCompat` and according to the documentation, I can get the current session somehow:

*"Once a session is created the owner of the session may pass its session token to other processes to allow them to create a MediaControllerCompat to interact with the session."*

```
    public class MediaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MediaBrowserCompat mMediaBrowserCompat;
    private MediaControllerCompat mMediaControllerCompat;
    private Activity mActivity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_media);

        mActivity = this;
        mPlayButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_play);

        mMediaBrowserCompat = new MediaBrowserCompat(
                getApplicationContext(),
                new ComponentName(mContext, MediaPlayerService.class),
                mMediaBrowserCompatConnectionCallback,
                getIntent().getExtras()
        );  

        mMediaBrowserCompat.connect();       

        mPlayButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if( mCurrentState == STATE_PAUSED ) {
                        getSupportMediaController().getTransportControls().play();
                        mCurrentState = STATE_PLAYING;
                        mPlayButton.setText("Pause");
                } else {
                    MediaControllerCompat.getMediaController(mActivity).getTransportControls().pause();
                    mCurrentState = STATE_PAUSED;
                    mPlayButton.setText("Play");
                }
            }
        });

        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();

            if (MediaControllerCompat.getMediaController(mActivity).getPlaybackState().getState() == PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING) {
                mPlayButton.setText("Pause")
            }
            else{
                mPlayButton.setText("Play")     
            }

        }       

        private MediaBrowserCompat.ConnectionCallback mMediaBrowserCompatConnectionCallback = new MediaBrowserCompat.ConnectionCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onConnected() {
                super.onConnected();
                try {
                    mMediaControllerCompat = new MediaControllerCompat(PodcastEpisodeActivity.this, mMediaBrowserCompat.getSessionToken());
                    mMediaControllerCompat.registerCallback(mMediaControllerCompatCallback);
                    MediaControllerCompat.setMediaController(mActivity, mMediaControllerCompat);
                    MediaControllerCompat.getMediaController(mActivity).getTransportControls().playFromUri(Uri.parse("http://www.url.com"), extras);

                } catch( RemoteException e ) {
                    Log.e(mActivity.getPackageName(), e.toString());
                }
            }
        };


        private MediaControllerCompat.Callback mMediaControllerCompatCallback = new MediaControllerCompat.Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onPlaybackStateChanged(PlaybackStateCompat state) {
                super.onPlaybackStateChanged(state);

                if (state == null ) return;

                switch (state.getState()) {
                    case PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING: {
                        mCurrentState = STATE_PLAYING;
                        break;
                    }
                    case PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PAUSED: {
                        mCurrentState = STATE_PAUSED;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out a way through the available API, so I'm just tracking which media is being played through local storage (sqlite) and updating the display through that.  Probably not the most elegant solution but it works.